# Rendering problems - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio

I have the following problem:

> **Rendering Problems** 
>   Couldn't resolve resource
>   @string/add_new_todo_item_string

I'm trying to use a string resource in a Textview. These are my XML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/add_new_todo_item_string"
    android:textSize="24sp" >

</TextView>
```

XML file for string resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">UILabs</string>
    <string name="done_string">Done:</string>
    <string name="priority_string">Priority:</string>
    <string name="date_string">Date:</string>
    <string name="add_new_todo_item_string">Add New ToDo Item</string>
    <string name="title_string">Title</string>
    <string name="status_string">Status</string>
    <string name="not_done_string">Not Done</string>
    <string name="priority_low_string">Low</string>
    <string name="priority_medium_string">Medium</string>
    <string name="priority_high_string">High</string>
    <string name="time_and_date_string">Time and Date</string>
    <string name="no_date_set_string">0000&#8211;00&#8211;00</string>
    <string name="no_time_set_string">00:00:00</string>
    <string name="choose_date_string">Choose Date</string>
    <string name="choose_time_string">Choose Time</string>
    <string name="cancel_string">Cancel</string>
    <string name="reset_string">Reset</string>
    <string name="submit_string">Submit</string>
    <string name="enter_title_string">Enter Title</string>

</resources>
```

What I'm missing? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: 
I also have a problem with mi AndroidMAnifest.xml file

> Cannot resolve symbol '@string/app_name' less... (Ctrl+F1)  Validates
>   resource references inside Android XML files.

This is my androidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.todomanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ToDoManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddToDoActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the error is in the following lines

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometime it happens in **`Android Studio`**. So Please Clean Your Project & Rebuild

**`Build > Clean Project Then Build > Rebuild Project`**

Then Click **Invalidate Caches/Restart Options**

Comment: Is it because of the way Intellij and Android Studio work(the project structure ? ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: I'm sure you tried a "make clean" and restarted Android Studio, but if you didn't, you should.

Comment: Im gonna try it. Thank you friend

Answer (score 0):

The Android studio configures for multi-language support to the strings you mention. In order to resolve it follow the below steps,

1. In android studio, Right click the **strings.xml** under values folder.
2. Click on the **Open Translations Editor**
3. You can see the key value and the default value as **app_name and your app name** respectively.
4. Click the **+** on the left corner of the Translatons Editor.
5. In the new pop-up window, Enter all your key values and default values as like you mentioned in the strings.xml.
6. Now check the xml files, All your issues are resolved.